# Access UIScrollView content offset in a container view from the parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

I have a problem accessing the `ContentOffset` of a `UIScrollView`. I had no problem with this before, but this time the `UIScrollView` is inside a `Container View` linked to a `ViewController`.

To better understand my situation here's a scheme and a picture:

MenuViewController **=>** Container View **=>** ScrollView1ViewController **=>** ScrollView1

[image]

The `UIScrollView` which I have to get it's `ContentOffset` is linked using an `IBOutlet` in the `ScrollView1ViewController.h`.

So my question is: is it possible to know the `ContentOffset` of the `UIScrollView` from the `MenuViewController.m`? Maybe importing the IBOutlet inside `ScrollView1ViewController.h` in `MenuViewController.m`

**ScrollView1ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ScrollView1ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
}

@property (weak, nonatomic)    IBOutlet    UIScrollView    *scrollView1;

@end
```

**MenuViewController.m**

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "ScrollView1ViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()
{
}

@property (strong, nonatomic)    ScrollView1ViewController    *sV1VC;
@property (weak, nonatomic)      UIScrollView                 *scrollView1;

@end

/***/

- (void)scrollForward
{
    self.offsetPoint = self.scrollView1.contentOffset.x;

    if ((self.offsetPoint == 0))
    {
        [self.scrollView1 setContentOffset:CGPointMake(270, 0) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

If you need more code and/or pictures to better understand my problem don't hesitate to ask me.

Thanks

Comment: Is "sV1VC" connected/linked to your real ScrollView1ViewController or did you simply declared that property?

Comment: I simply declared that property, I din't linked it because it's not an IBOutlet. Should I set an IBOutlet for "sV1VC"?

Comment: Lol yeah, I mean connect it using Interface Builder using the Cmd + Drag the file owner thing to the @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet ScrollView1ViewController *sV1VC so that it's connected, that way, when you refer to sV1VC, it's actually referring to your ScrollView1ViewController. Then you can use self.sV1VC.scrollView1.contentOffset.x (you will also need to connect your scrollView1 to your actual Interface Builder scrollView of ScrollView1ViewController.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one way in which I could see this is if you make a function to return the contentOffset of your scrollview in your ScrollView1ViewController

```
- (CGRect)returnContentOffSet
{
    return myScrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

and the try to call that method from MenuViewController

Answer (score 0):

When you setup your container view controller, you must have stored a reference to your ScrollView1ViewController as a property or an instance inside an array in the event your have multiple sub view controllers:

```
@interface MenuViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) ScrollView1ViewController *subVC1;
...

@end
```

So given, that you have a reference to the ScrollView1ViewController, can you simply not go:

```
// ------------------------------------------------
// Example button tap to get scrollview offset
// this method is inside your MenuViewController.m
// ------------------------------------------------
-(void)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint contentOffset = self.subVC1.scrollView.contentOffset;

    NSLog(@"ScrollView contentOffset = %lf, %lf", contentOffset.x, contentOffset.y);
}
```

Note:

I'm assuming here, in your ScrollView1ViewController, you have a reference to the scrollView as a property.

Does that help?

Comment: Hello @Zhang, thanks for your answer. I tried adding your code to MenuViewController, but nothing changed. I will update my question with more code.